# Case insensitive dictionary in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In C# there is the possibility to create case insensitive dictionaries (for keys of type string) using the `StringComparer`:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

I am looking for the same functionality in TypeScript, but searching online, it looks as if this is not built into TypeScript yet.

As a workaround I am currently using `toLowerCase()` everywhere in my code where I add values to or read values from the dictionary. However this is prone to errors and I am looking for a better solution.

Example:
After adding a value

```
dict = {};
dict['keystring'] = 1;
```

I want to be able to access it using `dict['keystring]` or `dict['KEYSTRING']` without worrying about correct casing. What is the recommended approach to solve this in TypeScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At runtime you can get fairly close to what you're asking for using a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

TypeScript can't do much to help with strongly typing the keys past just `string`, since the type system does not have the ability to represent the effect of string operations on [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types).  So if you wanted an object with `keystring` as a known key, the compiler would have no idea that `KEYSTRING` was also a known key.  There are suggestions for manipulating string literal types, such as [using regular expressions on them](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579), but nothing is currently part of the language.  Luckily for you, I think, you're asking for a dictionary type, which usually means the keys are just `string`.  As long as you don't expect the compiler to keep track of valid keys for you, you'll be okay.

Here's a possible implementation of using a `Proxy`.  Note that I haven't completely tested every possible edge case, but the basic idea is to get in the way of everything that accepts a property key and replace it with a canonical version:

```
function dictWithCanonicalKeys<V>(canon: (prop: keyof any) => keyof any) {
  return new Proxy<{ [k: string]: V }>(
    {},
    {
      get(target, prop) {
        return Reflect.get(target, canon(prop));
      },
      set(target, prop, value) {
        return Reflect.set(target, canon(prop), value);
      },
      has(target, prop) {
        return Reflect.has(target, canon(prop));
      },
      defineProperty(target, prop, attribs) {
        return Reflect.defineProperty(target, canon(prop), attribs);
      },
      deleteProperty(target, prop) {
        return Reflect.deleteProperty(target, canon(prop));
      },
      getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, prop) {
        return Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, canon(prop));
      }
    }
  );
}
```

And let's use it, passing in a canonicalizing function that converts the key to lowercase (if it's a `string`, that is... it leaves [`symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) keys alone):

```
const dict = dictWithCanonicalKeys<number | undefined>(
  p => (typeof p === "string" ? p.toLowerCase() : p)
);

dict.keyString = 1;
console.log(dict.KEYSTRING); // 1
dict.KEYstring = "two"; // error! "two" is not a number
dict.KEYstring = 2; 
console.log(dict.keyStrinG); // 2
console.log(JSON.stringify(dict)); // {"keystring": 2};
console.log("KeyString" in dict); // true
Object.keys(dict).forEach(k => console.log(k + ":" + dict[k])); // keystring:2
```

That all looks reasonable to me.

---

Finally, a caveat: you should be careful introducing things like this to your code.  It would be quite surprising to most developers to find that their supposedly plain objects have case-insensitive keys (`console.log(Object.keys(dict).indexOf("keyString")); // -1?!`), and even if you can explain it to developers, their IDEs will not understand and might flag a key that differs in case from an expected one  (e.g., `KeyString`) as an error.   If you're doing this to deal with user input, it might be cleaner to just define strict barriers where the input is allowed into your program, and canonicalize the case there, so the dictionary can be blissfully unaware and be implemented as a plain object.

Of course, only you know your use case, and maybe a case-insensitive dictionary-like object is the right choice.  If so, I hope the above code helps you.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAExtA6jKALAwgQzATXwBsBpAUwE8BnAHgDUA+ACgkIQC5FWAHAE5w+PANY04wRIWoBKRAF5micdUnSwcxAG8AUIkQDKUEAKRhKAd0QAFIQA9q9bYgDaonrSgCYYAOYAujyMiAC+bPoGOqEANJEGelFRfsasUPgCKVAxiILC8olJUUYmZogASpTApJTQAHRZaRlZORxEYPxCfLKyANzxUbEDBrSp6ZnGOXl8OQBuZCCUBcPFxqZIldW1UHWjUE0T2YhtCJ35cwtL-UVhcTfY+LQHLbldyzcGJesVVTX1D09xi8Th1pj1rkUhjdkFVfJQ7MJKAIoNRnpNXsIcvgoN4YAAjWjvD5fMqbP47GHAOEIvhIlFoo4gs7dLE4nwEvorKFFGE1KDwrp01FA9FgnQrT5rUm-bZ1XnGAWI5HC5roplgzk3blJLIAeUsYBpQoAIpRaBAfHwoHABAypm9xR9DFKNjL6nqDUblabzZbrbaRYzOKC3prIQNQpFOZHdBAEF4UGgoIpExgsHhgyQKDQGGAQABbPFIxAAH0Q4EpcOQEQMfEUyjS1Fp6jrCjbiAARF4fP4O4gAPy5OrWgAycEsSIIo1Y8h43V0nN0qHqqgAyrj-CmAIz9ONgWhwGp1UhwPysZc7cgAUQAmquACrlACSADkAOJ9RAAei-iC3S6TOprxvbtfD8FMOygSw4A7Xpv1-JEhAEABCTsoJgxAYFoRAiGTfAcILIsBAA+pgNAzcFEQAAmODY3jQ9KGPU9z0AtcNw-OCf2ouj9wYpizwAKVXXUX12Dc-BgYBUQvcF4J0DtVHIvwOx4KjQl3eijxPM8Oyoah1x7ZTMKQGTON-bxFl0XU8QAK1lRSWOgWQ6mAG0r3wCBsFYUR62OTTGO07zEAAak7Lg+1Ci93ACWSuMU8SuCo3QeIPLTmOsuyVxzRyoGc3wYXsXVgFYBSaAMsCO1i38AFot37ZDkqAA)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. A plain JS object with dynamically added properties is not really a general purpose dictionary anyway. The true equivalent in JS is the [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), but that also [does not support replacing the comparison operator](https://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-maps-sets.html) for keys.

Your approach is probably the best option. You can formalise it by wrapping the storage (your plain JS object or a `Map`) inside a wrapper object that ensures all operations using keys will make them lowercase before performing comparisons or lookups.